# Eclipse outline of Prototype javascript classes

Tags: javascript, eclipse, prototypejs

Is there a way to show the structure of a javascript class declared using Prototype's Class.create function in the Eclipse outline view?

The declarations look like:

```
var Foo = Class.create({
  bar: function() {
    ...
  },

  baz: function() {
    ...
  },
});
```

At the moment all I get is "Foo:".

(A google search turned up http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/prototypewtp, but the link to the plugin homepage is dead)

Answer (score 2):

There is the SPket plugin for eclipse wich support various js libraries. Its only free only for personal use though.

http://spket.com/prototypejs.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no plug-in that I know of that does this.

The convention is that javascript outlines show properties by name. Foo is the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Netbeans. Netbeans recognizes 'Class.create', see http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=149001